# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' when using Google maps route

Tags: ios, swift3

The below code works fine in `Xcode 7.1` but when I upgrade to `Xcode 8` and `swift 3` I get this error, I had searched on internet for same problem in stackoverflow but none of them answer my question.

```
func drawRoute() {


    clearRoute()
    //  self.routePolyline = nil
    // self.routePolyline.map = nil


    let route = mapTk.overviewPolyline!["points"] as String //error here

    //var overViewPolyLine = routes![0]["overview_polyline"]["points"].string

    let path: GMSPath = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: route)
    routePolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    routePolyline.map = viewMap
}
```

here is the class mapTK for more info:

```
import Foundation


import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

///This Class is designed for the detail methods that contact google maps server like GeoCode, GetDirection and Calculate distance and time
class MapTK: NSObject {
    let baseURLGeocode = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"

    var lookupAddressResults: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!

    var fetchedFormattedAddress: String!

    var fetchedAddressLongitude: Double!

    var fetchedAddressLatitude: Double!


    let baseURLDirections = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"

    var selectedRoute: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!

    var overviewPolyline: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!

    var originCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

    var destinationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

    var originAddress: String!

    var destinationAddress: String!

    var totalDistanceInMeters: UInt = 0

    var totalDistance: String!

    var totalDurationInSeconds: UInt = 0

    var totalDuration: String!



    /*  private let errorDictionary = ["NOT_FOUND" : "At least one of the locations specified in the request's origin, destination, or waypoints could not be geocoded",
    "ZERO_RESULTS":"No route could be found between the origin and destination",
    "MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED":"Too many waypointss were provided in the request The maximum allowed waypoints is 8, plus the origin, and destination",
    "INVALID_REQUEST":"The provided request was invalid. Common causes of this status include an invalid parameter or parameter value",
    "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT":"Service has received too many requests from your application within the allowed time period",
    "REQUEST_DENIED":"Service denied use of the directions service by your application",
    "UNKNOWN_ERROR":"Directions request could not be processed due to a server error. Please try again"]

    */

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

        ///the geocodeAddress is getting information from googlemaps with JSON it receive the geocode information
    func geocodeAddress(address: String!, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping ((_: String, _: Bool) -> Void)) {
        if let lookupAddress = address {
            var geocodeURLString = baseURLGeocode + "address=" + lookupAddress
            //geocodeURLString = geocodeURLString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!






            let geocodeURL = NSURL(string: geocodeURLString)

           // dispatch_Dispatch.Queue.mainasync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let geocodingResultsData = NSData(contentsOf: geocodeURL! as URL)

               // let error: NSError?

               do
               {
                let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: geocodingResultsData! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary


                // try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(directionsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
              /*
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error)
                    completionHandler(status: "", success: false)
                }

*/
 //               else {
                    // Get the response status.
                    let status = dictionary?["status"]as! String
              //   let status = dictionary["status"] as! [AnyObject]



                    if status == "OK" {
                        let allResults = dictionary?["results"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
                        self.lookupAddressResults = allResults[0]

                        // Keep the most important values.
                        self.fetchedFormattedAddress = self.lookupAddressResults["formatted_address"]? as? String
                        let geometry = self.lookupAddressResults["geometry"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                        self.fetchedAddressLongitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lng"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
                        self.fetchedAddressLatitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lat"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

                        completionHandler(status, true)
                    }
                    else {
                        completionHandler(status, false)
                    }
               } catch let error as NSError {

                print(error)
                }
            }  
        }
        else {
            completionHandler("No valid address.", false)
        }
    }


    ///getDirection method is using JSON to receive waypoints for making route for drawing polyline, as its name suggests it get the direciton inforamtion, first it send lat and lng the receive a dictionary and that dictionary give all the infrmation need to draw route like waypoints

    func getDirections(origin: String!, destination: String!, waypoints: Array<String>!, travelMode: TravelModes!, completionHandler: @escaping ((_ status: String, _ success: Bool) -> Void)) {
        if let originLocation = origin {
            if let destinationLocation = destination {
                var directionsURLString = baseURLDirections + "origin=" + originLocation + "&destination=" + destinationLocation //+ "&key=AIzaSyDsDqj0EMYZ-C4lGF3tmbntZtzurLl6_J4"



                if let routeWaypoints = waypoints {
                    directionsURLString += "&waypoints=optimize:true"

                    for waypoint in routeWaypoints {
                        directionsURLString += "|" + waypoint
                    }
                }
                if let _ = travelMode {
                    var travelModeString = ""

                    switch travelMode.rawValue {
                    case TravelModes.walking.rawValue:
                        travelModeString = "walking"

                    case TravelModes.bicycling.rawValue:
                        travelModeString = "bicycling"

                    default:
                        travelModeString = "driving"
                    }




                directionsURLString += "&mode=" + travelModeString
            }


              //  directionsURLString = directionsURLString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

              //  directionsURLString = directionsURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

             //  directionsURLString = directionsURLString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!



                /// directionsURLString = directionsURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                directionsURLString = directionsURLString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!


//let encodedHost = unencodedHost.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)

                //var url = NSURL(urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()))
                //let savePath = (documentDirectory as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov")

                let directionsURL = NSURL(string: directionsURLString)

              //  DispatchQueue.main.asynchronously(execute: { () -> Void in

                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let directionsData = NSData(contentsOf: directionsURL! as URL)

                   // var error: NSError?

                    do {
 let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: directionsData! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary


                        /*
                        if (error != nil) {
                        print(error)
                        completionHandler(status: "", success: false)
                    }
*/
                   // else {
                        let status = dictionary?["status"] as! String

                        if status == "OK" {
                            self.selectedRoute = (dictionary?["routes"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>)[0]
                            self.overviewPolyline = self.selectedRoute["overview_polyline"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                            let legs = self.selectedRoute["legs"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>

                            let startLocationDictionary = legs[0]["start_location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                            self.originCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, startLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                            let endLocationDictionary = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_location"]as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                            self.destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, endLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                            self.originAddress = legs[0]["start_address"] as! String
                            self.destinationAddress = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_address"] as! String

                            self.calculateTotalDistanceAndDuration()

                            completionHandler(status, true)

                        }
                        else {
                            completionHandler(status, false)
                        }



                    } catch let error as NSError {

                        print(error)
                    }

                  }
                    }



            else {
                completionHandler("Destination is nil.", false)
            }
        }

        else {
            completionHandler("Origin is nil", false)
        }

    }


/// this method below is for the calculation of Distance adn Duration of each location for travel

    func calculateTotalDistanceAndDuration() {
        let legs = self.selectedRoute["legs"] as! Array<NSDictionary>

        totalDistanceInMeters = 0
        totalDurationInSeconds = 0

        for leg in legs {
            totalDistanceInMeters += (leg["distance"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["value"] as! UInt
            totalDurationInSeconds += (leg["duration"]as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["value"] as! UInt
        }


        let distanceInKilometers: Double = Double(totalDistanceInMeters / 1000)
        totalDistance = "Total Distance: \(distanceInKilometers) Km"


        let mins = totalDurationInSeconds / 60
        let hours = mins / 60
        let days = hours / 24
        let remainingHours = hours % 24
        let remainingMins = mins % 60
        let remainingSecs = totalDurationInSeconds % 60

        totalDuration = "Duration: \(days) d, \(remainingHours) h, \(remainingMins) mins, \(remainingSecs) secs"
    }






}
```

Comment: What is the type of `mapTk` and `mapTk. overviewPolyline`.

Comment: it is a class where I put the methods for map like geocode and direction there

Comment: @sssaaan is `overviewPolyline` type of Dictionary?

Comment: what is the type of `mapTk.overviewPolyline`. Is it `Dictionary` or `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I edit the question and put all the mapTK as well

Comment: its of type Dictionary

Comment: @sssaaan Change `var overviewPolyline: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!` to `var overviewPolyline = [String, Any]()`

Comment: In Swift 3 NSObject doesn't working with subscript.

Comment: xcode does not accept this type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Dictionary<String, Any>
```

as JSON dictionary type.

JSON keys are required to be `String` anyway and
`AnyObject` has been changed to `Any` in Swift 3.

**Edit** :

I recommend to use a type alias for the JSON dictionary type

```
typealias JSONObject = [String:Any] // synonym of Dictionary<String, Any>
```

Then you can write

```
var lookupAddressResults: JSONObject!
... 
var selectedRoute: JSONObject!
var overviewPolyline: JSONObject!
```

and the parsing code

```
...
    if status == "OK" {
        let allResults = dictionary?["results"] as! Array<JSONObject>
        self.lookupAddressResults = allResults[0]

        // Keep the most important values.
        self.fetchedFormattedAddress = self.lookupAddressResults["formatted_address"] as? String
        let geometry = self.lookupAddressResults["geometry"] as! JSONObject
        self.fetchedAddressLongitude = ((geometry["location"] as! JSONObject)["lng"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
        self.fetchedAddressLatitude = ((geometry["location"] as! JSONObject)["lat"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

        completionHandler(status, true)
      }

...
```

You can also replace

```
( ... as! NSNumber).doubleValue
```

with

```
... as! Double
```

Comment: it does not accept this type Dictionary<String, Any>, alert me to put ; after String

Comment: I think its require a () after this, that way worked